# Error al enviar token con HttpInterceptor en Angular Versión 11.2.12

Tags: angular

Estoy intentando consumir un Servicio enviando un token en Angular usando `HttpInterceptor` pero recibo un error en mi class de `AuthInterceptor`:

Hago las pruebas en Postman y sirve perfecto.

Obtener la información de un usuario y demás métodos enviando el token.

Lógica y error por método:

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer MI-AUTH-TOKEN',
            },
        });

        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    console.log('Evento: ', event);
                }
                return event;
            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {

                console.log('Error de HttpInterceptor: ', error);
                return throwError(error);
            }));
    }
}


//==========>>>>> ERROR DE ESTE METODO

>> Mensaje del método:

Error de HttpInterceptor:  
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/tutorial/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo", ok: false, …}
> error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
> headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/tutorial/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/tutorial/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"
> __proto__: HttpResponseBase

>>>> ERROR DE CORS EN LA CONSOLA DEL NAVEGADOR

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/tutorial/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Método que consume el api:
El error que me arroja este es el mismo de arriba `Error de HttpInterceptor:` en el mensaje del método del Intercept

```
getInformatioUser() {
    this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/tutorial/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo').subscribe({
      next: (response: any) => {
        console.log('Response: ', response);
      }, error(response: any) {
        console.log('Error al obtener info de usuario: ', response);
      }
    });
  }
```

Mi app.module.ts:
Este esta bien.

```
providers: [{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
    multi: true,
    deps: [KeycloakService],
  }, {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AuthInterceptor,
    multi: true,
  },
    UsuarioServiceService,
    RolServiceService,
    AreaServiceService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Comment: En Postman te funciona, porque el que enforza la restricción de CORS es el navegador.

Comment: @JhonRM ya encontré solución y ya logre obtener la información del usuario por medio de token sobre KeyCloak ahora tengo el error es al obtener la lista de usuarios en mi API-REST por CORS pero dejare la solución de como se usa el request con el header.

Igual gracias.

Answer (score -1):

La solución fue hacerlo de esta manera.

```
req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer AUTH-TOKEN') });
```

Comment: Viendo el uso que estás dando a los headers, creo que no te ha quedado claro cómo funciona CORS: el header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ha de ser añadido en la respuesta por el backend, no en la petición.

Comment: @PabloLozano, Si disculpa se me olvido quitarlo ya edite la respuesta.

Comment: Lo mismo ocurre con `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, todo CORS es un asunto de backend aceptando o no peticiones y avisando al navegador "de antemano"